# Laravel - issue with compiled.php

Tags: php, google-app-engine, laravel, laravel-4

I am relatively new to Laravel, but not PHP. I am trying to get it to work on AppEngine but I am having some difficulties. I have gone through a lot of the errors and fixed them but I can't seem to get around this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::getMonolog()
```

When I did check the class it said was missing the function it turned out to be correct. I went searching online to see if I could find the getMonolog function to no avail. Does any one have any code that pertains to this function?

Also it seems that my compiled.php file keeps producing these issues. I have tried:

```
composer update
```

This produces the following error:

```
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-update-cmd event returned with an error

[Runtime Exception]
Error Output:
```

I also ran:

```
php artisan update
```

That produced no output what so ever. I think there might be an issue with my artisan class as even `php artisan --version` produces no output. Any ideas on how to proceed with this issue?

Comment: Try to manually delete `vendor/compiled.php`

Comment: Tried that. But I do not have composer.phar which apparently regenerates the compiled.php file

Comment: Composer has nothing to do with `compiled.php`

Comment: Just deleted the compiled.php file and still get the same issue

Comment: You may be interested in using the official starter app for Laravel on Google App Engine: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/laravel